# Rails Engines: When to put code in app, when in lib, and when in vendor folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

I'm developing a Rails engine, and so I've taken some looks on existing ones. I noticed that many of them have files in `app`, but also in `lib` and `vendor`.

It's clear to me that I should put any code that should be replaceable by the host app into the `app` folder (e.g. when having a model `app/user.rb`, the host app can easily have its own `app/user.rb` file and use this one instead of the engine one's).

But I'm unsure, when I have to put stuff in to `lib`, and when into `vendor`? I thought, that in `vendor`, I should only put "external" code from other developers or projects, that I want to use in my project, and in `lib` I put my own additional libraries that I'm actually working on in the project. But why, for example, does WiceGrid put stuff into its [wice_grid/vendor/assets](https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid/tree/rails3/vendor/assets) directory? It doesn't look to me like external code, but code that is developed only for WiceGrid and hence should be in the `lib` directory?

**Update**

While experimenting a bit, I noticed that all code in the `lib` folder is not reloaded while developing the engine (I guess the same is the case for the `vendor` directory), so I should put them into a folder within `app`, but where exactly?

For example, I have a file `lib/iq_list_controller.rb` that holds some class and instance methods for `ApplicationController` which I mix into it in `engine.rb` like this:

```
initializer "wice_grid_railtie.configure_rails_initialization" do |app|
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
    extend  IqList::Controller::ClassMethods
    include IqList::Controller::InstanceMethods
  end
end
```

Where should I put this file so Ruby properly finds it?

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the development reloading issue, if the lib folder is a natural home for your files, then add it to Rails' load path with something like:

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    config.autoload_paths << File.expand_path("../../lib", __FILE__)
  end
end
```

Regarding the specific case of vendor assets, it seems reasonable to place your engine's assets in app/assets, where they will be found by the host Rails app.

Answer (score 2):

if you want things to be autoloaded then put them in `/app`. Otherwise I think that anything in `/lib` should be manually required. I generally believe that autoloading the lib folder is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

your basic code for MVC comes in app folder.now suppose you have a generic method/module which is frequently used,so to implement DRYness for your code...all generic and common utilities can be simply put in lib folder.

theres a beautiful explaination [when to use lib](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ruby/2012/02/14/love-your-lib-directory.html) and [using lib folder in rails](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/02/07/what-code-goes-in-the-lib-directory/)